# UK Tier 4 Visa and Passport Sent Back

Tags: visas, uk, vfs-global

I would very greatly appreciate any advice.

Here is my situation. I am applying from the US for a Tier 4 student visa for study in the UK. I successfully applied, got my biometrics, sent my documents and passport to New York for my application to be processed, and then VFS global sent my visa and passport to my home address. (Presumably my visa was approved, but I was never notified about that). UPS tried to drop off the package (visa and passport), but I wasn't home to collect the package, so they returned the package to sender, which presumably was VFS Global in Schengen (UPS told me this).

Unfortunately, VFS Global UK does not have a phone number or email address, but they do have a customer complaint email that I emailed two weeks ago. They told me that my "complaint" was forwarded to the relevant team and I should hear back soon, but that was 13 days ago. I have called UK visa and immigrations to see if they have my visa and passport (which could be anywhere at this point), and they said they would do an investigation and let me know in 15 business days, and that was 9 business days ago. I am skeptical that investigation will work out, since I also emailed UK visa and immigrations and they told me I have to contact VFS Global (but I think this might be a fast/loose reply).

My international flight is in less than a week, and I highly doubt I will get my visa and passport back before then. Since I doubt that VFS Global or UK visa and immigrations will resolve my issue, I am looking into alternatives, but my knowledge of passport and visa issues is very limited. I was wondering if I could get a new passport, use it to fly to the UK, and somehow get my visa at the US embassy in the UK. I am not sure if I am allowed to get a new passport if my passport is not officially lost (though it very well may be lost). I'm also not sure if I can get my visa or get approved to study in the UK at the US embassy in the UK.

Any other ideas or advice would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98315/discussion-between-chx-and-mathworker21).

Comment: Why is this on hold?????

Comment: Because a Tier 4 visa is for immigration. I answered you in chat because it doesn't quite matter which tier you are on.

Comment: @chx Is immigration not allowed to be talked about on this site? Anyways, I called UPS and spoke to a supervisor, and they said that they just didn't have any phone number for VFS. Also, I was wrong: they held it for 7 days, not 3. Apparently, my parents didn't tell me about the sticker for a while.

Comment: I told you to insist. They are taking VFS mail every day, they must have a way to contact them, if nothing else then when they pick up the mail.